# Make gcc coloring the default

Tags: 12.04, gcc, environment-variables

Is there a way to automatically make gcc color its output?

I am looking to avoid an alias as the the command is commonly used in makefiles (where it will not be used).

Is there an easy way to do this?

**Note:** this does require gcc/g++ 4.9, which is currently available via svn. I am willing to recompile if the change is something small (in a config file or something).

I know that the [GCC_COLOR environment variable](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Language-Independent-Options.html) is used, but I am not sure how to set it, or what to set it to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add to your `.bashrc`:

```
export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'
```

But note that GCC 4.9 is under heavy development, so the defaults may change.

Comment: This did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: You need at least r198332.